# .vue file syntax coloring doesn't work in pyCharm

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7gOv.png)

Hi. I have problem with colouring .vue file syntax in my pyCharm. The version of pyCharm is 2018.1.4 . Vue plugin is intalled, settings for javascript language is ECMASript 6. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `*.vue` is a registered pattern for **Vue.js Template**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was it... I didn't have Registered Patterns *.vue